# Request validation using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework for the backend. How can I implement request validation? (do not want to write validation inside lambda functions).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To implement request validation using `serverless` you need to do a couple of things:
Include your model/header definitions in your stack, and then tell API gateway to use them for request validation.

You'll need to install the following packages:

- [`serverless-aws-documentation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-aws-documentation)
- [`serverless-reqvalidator-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-reqvalidator-plugin)

And then you'll need to include them in your `serverless.yml`:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
  - serverless-aws-documentation
```

Note: below is only a quick run-down of how to incorporate the packages. Visit the packages' documentation pages for more comprehensive examples...

1. Provide API gateway with a description of your models / headers.

   You can import json schemas for your models, and declare http headers using the `serverless-aws-documentation` plugin.
   Here's how you'd add a model to your `serverless.yml`:

   ```
   custom:
     documentation:
       api:
         info:
           version: v0.0.0
           title: Some API title
           description: Some API description
       models:
         - name: SomeLambdaRequest
           contentType: application/json
           schema: ${file(models/SomeLambdaRequest.json)} # reference to your model's json schema file. You can also declare the model inline.
   ```

   And here's how you'd reference the model in your lambda definition:

   ```
   functions:
     someLambda:
       handler: src/someLambda.handler
       events:
         - http:
             # ... snip ...
             documentation:
               summary: some summary
               description: some description
               requestBody:
                 description: some description
               requestModels:
                 application/json: SomeLambdaRequest
   ```

   You can also declare request headers against your lambda definition like so:

   ```
   functions:
     someLambda:
       handler: src/someLambda.handler
       events:
         - http:
             # ... snip ...
             documentation:
               summary: some summary
               description: some description
               requestHeaders:
                 - name: x-some-header
                   description: some header value
                   required: true # true or false
                 - name: x-another-header
                   description: some header value
                   required: false # true or false
   ```
2. Tell API gateway to actually use the models for validation

   This part makes use of the `serverless-reqvalidator-plugin` package, and you need to add `AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator` resources to your `serverless.yml` file.
   You can specify whether you want to validate request body, request headers, or both.

   ```
   resources:
     Resources:
       onlyBody:
         Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
         Properties:
           Name: 'only-body'
           RestApiId:
             Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
           ValidateRequestBody: true # true or false
           ValidateRequestParameters: false # true or false
   ```

   And then on individual functions you can make use of the validator like so:

   ```
   functions:
     someLambda:
       handler: src/someLambda.handler
       events:
         - http:
             # ... snip ...
             reqValidatorName: onlyBody # reference and use the 'only-body' request validator
   ```

Put all together your lambda definition would end up looking a little like this:

```
functions:
  someLambda:
    handler: src/someLambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          # ... snip ...
          reqValidatorName: onlyBody # reference and use the 'only-body' request validator
          documentation:
            summary: some summary
            description: some description
            requestBody:
              description: some description
            requestModels:
              application/json: SomeLambdaRequest
            requestHeaders:
              - name: x-some-header
                description: some header value
                required: true # true or false
              - name: x-another-header
                description: some header value
                required: false # true or false
```

Comment: any comments on this ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317704/how-to-do-serverless-binary-configuration-right

Answer (score 36):

This is now supported by Serverless framework, so there is no need to use external plugins.

To enable requests validation one need is to add the following to the `serverless.yml`:

```
  HttpHandler:
    handler: src/lambda/http/create.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: post
          path: items
          request:
            schemas:
              application/json: ${file(models/create-todo-model.json)}
```

Instead of keeping the file location directly under `application/json` you can also keep the name of the model after defining it under `serverless.yml` file's `apiGateway` section. [link to documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-schema-validators)

**Kindly note** that, as of Feb-2022, serverless-offline plugin is not validating the `http.request.schemas` in your local. Though they are supporting deprecated version `http.request.schema`.

Comment: How do you _require_ the content-type to be application/json? With this example, if you don't provide a request body or provide a different content-type, the Lambda is still invoked.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. If the content-type different than the `application/json` still Lambda invoked. Is there way to configure AWS API gateway to only allow  `application/json`, content-type ?

Comment: [API Gateway Request Validation](https://rboyd.dev/089999bf-b973-42ed-9796-6167539269b8) suggests that you can't properly enforce content type validation with the default Lambda-Proxies integration yet. In order to avoid content type issues, you need to use the (in case of serverless non default) [Lambda integration](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#lambda-integration) and use "Never" as passThrough behaviour (which is default in case you don't specify anything). This will then block content types which were not defined by the setup provided.

Comment: I still prefer the accepted answer because you can define an OpenApi documentation as well as the request validation.

Comment: how can we validate query string parameters?

Answer (score 4):

As Ivan indicated, there is no need for external plugins as this is supported by the Serverless framework. However, I think the way to configure this has changed.

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(create_request.json)}
```

This example was taken from: 
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-schema-validators

Comment: ```NOTE: schema validators are only applied to content types you specify. Other content types are not blocked.```

Comment: should be `schemas`, instead of `schema`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are like me and you don't want to add plugins as suggested in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133294/request-validation-using-serverless-framework".

If you set parameters as required and want to validate them, you must add a request validator to your *serverless.yml*

```
Resources:
  ParameterRequestValidator:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator
    Properties:
      Name: ParameterRequestValidator
      RestApiId:
        Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
      ValidateRequestBody: false
      ValidateRequestParameters: true

  ApiGatewayMethodNameOfYourApiLookItUpInYourTemplate:
    Properties:
      RequestValidatorId:
        Ref: ParameterRequestValidator
```

The method you want to validate will be named something like `ApiGateway<Method><Get | Post | Patch | Put | Delete >:`. You can look the name up when you package your serverless functions in the created template files.

Courtesy for this solutions goes to https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/5034#issuecomment-581832806

Comment: I got this error on trying the above: An error occurred: ApiGatewayResourceResourceDashdata - Encountered unsupported property RequestValidatorId.

Comment: Please make sure that your resource name is correct. See also the comments on this answer that elaborates on it https://stackoverflow.com/a/61798760/5493813

Comment: @ShwetaJ please upvote the answers if you feel they helped you

Answer (score -1):

Request validation using serverless

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
  - serverless-reqvalidator-plugin
  - serverless-aws-documentation
  
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: get
  likes:
    handler: handler.likes
    events:
      - http:
          path: /likes
          method: get
          integration: lambda
          reqValidatorName: xMyRequestValidator
          request:
            passThrough: NEVER
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                userid: true
                activityid: true
            template:
              application/json: '{ "userid":"$input.params(''userid'')","activityid":"$input.params(''activityid'')"}'
          response:
            headers:
              Content-Type: "'application/json'"

custom:
  wsgi:
    app: handler.app
    pythonBin: python # Some systems with Python3 may require this
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
resources:
  Resources:
    xMyRequestValidator:  
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RequestValidator"
      Properties:
        Name: 'my-req-validator'
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        ValidateRequestBody: true
        ValidateRequestParameters: true
```