# Lambda request validator: using variables inside schema json file

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless

I want to do (http) request parameters validation for lambda functions using serverless framework.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504119/2076973) explains how to do it, using API Gateway request validation using [JSON Schema draft](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-schema-validators).

It allows one to validate a given endpoint, using a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "user Schema",
  "required": ["name", "age"],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Name",
      "pattern": "(?=^.{6,23}$)(^(\\p{L}\\p{M}*)+$)"
    }
  }
}
```

where a property `name` inside `body` is expected to have between 6 and 23 characters, through a Regex validator.

However, I'd like to have these values be exported from a file, to be more organized, such as a yml file:

```yaml
# validator-config.yml
VALIDATOR_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH: 6
VALIDATOR_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH: 23
VALIDATOR_REGEX_CHARACTER: "(\\p{L}\\p{M}*)"
```

and use it as:

```json
{
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title": "user Schema",
  "required": ["name", "age"],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Name",
      "pattern": "(?=^.{VALIDATOR_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,VALIDATOR_USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH}$)(^VALIDATOR_REGEX_CHARACTER+$)"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?